# SymPy - Solving for variable in equation

Tags: python, sympy

Is it possible to define an equation and solve a variable in that equation?

```
D_PWM, Rsense, A = symbols('D_PWM, Rsense, A')

i_out = D_PWM * (A/Rsense)

print i_out

solve(i_out, Rsense)
```

Result:

```
A*D_PWM/Rsense
[]
```

Comment: `[]` means that this equation has no solution for `Rsense`. See solution (as example) for `solve(i_out-5, Rsense)`

Comment: I see. I guess I'm not looking to solve, but rather rearrange the equation for Rsense = '...'

Comment: `solve` means `rearrange for Rsense = ...` but  in your code `i_out = D_PWM * (A/Rsense)` means `i_out = "D_PWM * (A/Rsense) = 0"` so you try `solve("D_PWM * (A/Rsense) = 0", Rsense)` but `"D_PWM * (A/Rsense) = 0"` can't be rearranged to `Rsense = ...`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**i_out** has not been declared as a symbol.

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('D_PWM, Rsense, A i_out')
(D_PWM, Rsense, A, i_out)
>>> eqn=Eq(i_out,D_PWM * (A/Rsense))
>>> solve(eqn,Rsense)
[A*D_PWM/i_out]
```